# publickeytoken case-sensitivity - ASP.Net web.config issues

Tags: asp.net, publickeytoken

I recently went to deploy an asp.net solution to a Win2003 server.

I was getting error messages that referred to assemblies supposedly missing.

It transpires that the publickeytokens on my development machine (XP SP3 32bit) were in upper case whilst the same files on the server (can't check at this moment if it was 32 or 64 bit) had lower case publickeytokens.

(I used win explorer going to c:\windows\assembly)

Amending web.config so that the publickeytoken matched that of the assembly on the server did the trick and the app worked.

I've tried researching the reason for the difference but haven't found anything.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction as to why the publickeytokens on different machines would be in different cases?

Many Thanks

Neil

Comment: Assembly supposedly missing can mean that some libraries are missing in you project. Have you use external libraries in your project?

Comment: The files weren't missing - the publickeytokens were in different cases so the reference in web.config to a file with an uppercase publickeytoken produced a missing file message. Changing the reference in web.config to lower case allowed the application to work. My question is asking why is there a case difference

Comment: +1 Interested in knowing if the public key tokens are case sensitive.  In all of my experience I never ran across a mismatch.  What happens if you switch back one of the characters to a lower case? Obviously you don't want to do that on your production app, but maybe setup a test app.

Comment: Experiencing this right now, with some solutions that are .net 4.7, visual stiod 2019. Anyone has anthing that could help??

Comment: Old question, still an issue.  Visual Studio 2022 adds missing bindings with uppercase publicKeyTokens, while restoring NuGet packages will add them with lowercase tokens (creating duplicate entries). When deploying to our environment, the uppercase variants don't seem to work.